# Alpha-haloketone reaction with H2O in acid medium

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I need help with this reaction, I know that in the first step an alpha haloketone is formed, but I can't figure out what reaction is going to happen between the alpha Haloketone and $\ce{H2O/H+}$.
[image]

I read your answers and this is some information and assumptions that I can share.
For the reaction between the alpha haloketone and the $\ce{H2O/H+}$ ,I thought that the oxygen of the carbonyl could be protonated so the $\ce{C}$ atom becomes more electrophilic, then the water (the nucleophile) could attack that C atom of the carbonyl group.
[image]

I found a paper (Erian, A. W, 2003)  where they report a general mechanism for the reaction of alpha haloketones with nucleophiles
[image]

So, considering that, I thought this might be the product of this reaction.
[image]

What do you think? I'm not really sure of the answer, but that's what I have so far.

This is the complete reference:

Erian, A. W., Sherif, S. M., Gaber, H. M. (2003), "The chemistry of α-haloketones and their utility in heterocyclic synthesis", *Molecules*, **8**(11), 793–865. (https://doi.org/10.3390/81100793)

Comment: The conditions you describe for the first reaction is for a haloform reaction. Normally, acid is the catalyst. What are or your thoughts on the second reaction with a reactive chloroketone?

Comment: As usual, identify the nucleophile and identify the electrophile.

Comment: I edited the post, hope this can help, what are your thoughts?